# Serialize XML Attribute of Subelement

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I would like to directly serialize an attribute of an Subelement with an occurence of 0..1 into a property, like so:

```
public class Root {
    // Which attributes are needed here?
    public TestEnum TestEnum { get; set; }
}

public enum TestEnum {
 [XmlEnum("tst1")]
 Test1,
 [XmlEnum("tst2")]
 Test2
}
```

The XML Structure simplified:

```
<root>
    <Element testType="tst1"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
            Root root = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("root")]
    public class Root
    {
        // Which attributes are needed here?
        private TestEnum TestEnum { get; set; }

        public Element Element
        {
            get { Element e = new Element(); e.testType = TestEnum.ToString(); return e; }
            set { TestEnum = (TestEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TestEnum), value.testType); }

        }


    }
    public class Element
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string testType { get; set; }
    }

    public enum TestEnum
    {
        tst1,
        tst2
    }

}
```